# I sheduled an apex class to run everyday, but nothing happens. Can somebody help me out?

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code

I wrote this APEX class and sheduled it to run every day.I don't get an error message, but unfortunately the class doesn't do anything... Can anybody help me out?

```
global class CustomersDateCheck implements Schedulable {
global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
List<Customers__c> CustomerList = [SELECT Id FROM Customers__c];
DateCheck(CustomerList);}

public static void DateCheck(Customers__c[] objects){


  for(Customers__c obj: objects){

    if(obj.DateField > Date.today()){
            continue;}

        else{obj.FlowUpdateHelper__c = true;}
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you write the Schedulable now you need Schedule it.

run this 3 line of code in developer console then check apex jobs

```
//will run daily at 13:00 
CustomersDateCheck m = new CustomersDateCheck();
String sch = '0 0 13 * * ?';
String jobID = system.schedule('Customers Date Check Job', sch, m);
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm

Comment: I just spotted this error when accessing the apex jobs log:
SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Customers__c.DateField__c
What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

The error means you're trying to access something that you didn't include in the query, in this case the Customers__c.DateField__c , you need to either remove the reference to that, or update your query to include that info